# Cursor based pagination with ID and sorting with Boolean

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, database-cursor

Cursor based pagination was implemented by remembering the ID of the last item from the last result.

```
SELECT * FROM emojis WHERE id < $last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

And I wanted to sort it with `is_animated = true` first. So If I have:

```
| id    | is_animated   |
|-----  |-------------  |
| 100   | true          |
| 99    | false         |
| 98    | false         |
| 97    | true          |
| 96    | true          |
```

It should be ordered with `id DESC, is_animated DESC` and return the following result:

```
| id    | is_animated   |
|-----  |-------------  |
| 100   | true          |
| 97    | true          |
| 96    | true          |
| 99    | false         | <- But I will never get this,
| 98    | false         | <- and this because the IDs are greater than 96.
```

I don't know which field to use to be my cursor and what SQL to query the data since ordering by IDs is no longer reliable.

---

In the "[How to implement relay style cursor based pagination in postgres?](https://www.reddit.com/r/graphql/comments/uc7qrc/how_to_implement_relay_style_cursor_based/)" post, a SQL condition was mentioned:

```
WHERE (`name` > $last_name OR (`name` = $last_name AND `id` > $last_id))
ORDER BY `name` ASC, `id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

also the post "[Pagination with Relative Cursors](https://shopify.engineering/pagination-relative-cursors)" from Shopify

```
WHERE (`title` > "Pants" OR  (`title` = "Pants" AND `id` > 2))
ORDER BY `title` ASC, `id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

but they were used to sort with fields which are orderable (like alphabets and numerics).

---

How to use the similar conditions but sorting with booleans? And what parameters/arguments do I need to remember to be my cursor for querying the next page?

Comment: I don't see any pagination here. Check your code. Once you'll fix it, the rest will become clear.

Comment: Example updated, I missed the `LIMIT 10` thing- in my example so it seems unlike a "pagination". In the SQL `SELECT * FROM emojis WHERE id < $last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`, the `$last_id` is the _cursor_. User will pass the `$last_id` from the last result they fetched to get next 10 data which IDs are lesser than the `$last_id`.

Comment: Great. So, when you're talking about ordering the results by `is_animated`, are you referring to a single page results or the entire results?

Comment: I would like to ordering with a full table _then_ do the pagination. I think the answer @bill-karwin tells nearly all by using the UNIONs.

Comment: In that case, the ordering should obviously be done by the query who fetches the entire result set, pre pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the rows you want, you'd need:

```
WHERE is_animated < $last_is_animated OR id <= $last_id
```

But at this point, the optimization of the cursor-based pagination is lost. The `OR` expression is bound to result in a table-scan anyway.

By the way, if you want to sort first by `is_animated`, you'd need to list it first in the order:

```
ORDER BY is_animated DESC, id DESC
```

An alternative way to write this query could be:

```
(SELECT ... WHERE is_animated = true AND id < $last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT ... WHERE is_animated = false ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY is_animated DESC, id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This way if there are fewer than 5 rows matched by the first subquery, it'll fill the gap with a few rows from the second subquery.

Your code would need to check the `is_animated` of the last row fetched. If it's still `true`, then repeat the query. If the last row's `is_animated` is `false`, then on subsequent pages, change the query to run to the following:

```
SELECT ... WHERE is_animated = false ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Woah- interesting. And the last SQL you mentioned `SELECT ... WHERE is_animated = false ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;` It _should_ also contains the `id < $last_id` condition right? Using `UNION` and program conditions didn't come up in my mind. The instruction is very helpful.